# MVC 3 application date format issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Ok this is really driving me nuts, dates in my MVC 3 application will only show in American date format i.e. mm/dd/yy.

I have checked my systems location setting and everything is set to the UK, I've checked the globalisation settings in IIS and set those to United Kingdom. I have also added the following to my applications web.config:

```
<globalization uiCulture="en-GB" culture="en-GB" />
```

But still dates show in mm/dd/yy format! I have tried to format the dates in my views using .ToString() as follows:

```
@location.DateFrom.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
```

Still American format! Can someone please shed some light on this as its literally driving me insane, I can't even think of what else to change. Any help would be greatly appreciated, cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will certainly format for "en-GB":

```
@location.DateFrom.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-GB"))
```

You need to check the `Thread.CurrentCulture` and `Thread.CurrentUICulture` to see what they are returning.

Comment: Well this is a little embarrassing, all my dates are entered using the jQuery UI date picker and it seems it is that which has been messing things up. When I entered a date manually it is returned as expected. Apologies, but thanks for the quick response